# Is it possible to run code once per draw call in WebGL?

Tags: glsl, webgl, vertex-shader

I'm taking a course in WebGL at NTNU. I'm currently exploring what the shaders do and how I can use them.

An example we have shows us that we compute a projection matrix, then set it in the vertex shader, then make a draw call. I wanted to try to do this matrix computation in a shader.

This means I have to put the code somewhere else than the `main()` function in the vertex shader, since that one is invoked many times per draw call.

Vertex shader:

```
uniform vec3 camRotation;
attribute vec3 position;
void main() {

    // I want this code to run only once per draw call
    float rX = camRotation[0];
    float rY = camRotation[1];
    float rZ = camRotation[2];
    mat4 camMatrix = mat4(
        cos(rY) * cos(rZ), cos(rZ) * sin(rX) * sin(rY) - cos(rX) * sin(rZ), sin(rX) * sin(rZ) + cos(rX) * cos(rZ) * sin(rY), 0, //
        cos(rY) * sin(rZ), cos(rX) * cos(rZ) + sin(rX) * sin(rY) * sin(rZ), cos(rX) * sin(rY) * sin(rZ) - cos(rZ) * sin(rX), 0, //
        -sin(rY), cos(rY) * sin(rX), cos(rX) * cos(rY), 0, //
        0, 0, 0, 1
    );
    // End of code in question

    gl_Position = camMatrix * vec4(position, 1);
    gl_PointSize = 5.0;
}
```

Is it possible? Am I a fool for trying?

Comment: You might find [these articles useful](http://webglfundamentals.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way to do that. You should compute `camMatrix` in your JS code and pass it to the shader via uniform:

```
uniform mat4 camMatrix;
attribute vec3 position;
void main() {
    gl_Position = camMatrix * vec4(position, 1);
    gl_PointSize = 5.0;
}
```

Now you need to compute matrix in JS:

```
// assuming that program is your compiled shader program and
// gl is your WebGL context.
const cos = Math.cos;
const sin = Math.sin;
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'camMatrix'), [
    cos(rY) * cos(rZ), cos(rZ) * sin(rX) * sin(rY) - cos(rX) * sin(rZ), sin(rX) * sin(rZ) + cos(rX) * cos(rZ) * sin(rY), 0,
    cos(rY) * sin(rZ), cos(rX) * cos(rZ) + sin(rX) * sin(rY) * sin(rZ), cos(rX) * sin(rY) * sin(rZ) - cos(rZ) * sin(rX), 0,
    -sin(rY), cos(rY) * sin(rX), cos(rX) * cos(rY), 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware of the method you provide, I'm curios to see if I can do these computations (like `cos(rY)`) in the shader once per draw call

Comment: @Birger I'd be very surprised because of how GPU runs shaders. To describe crudely every execution of a shader (for every vertex, if we're talking about vertex shaders, and for every pixel in case of fragment shaders) gets its own state and chunk of memory. And synchronisation and exchanging data between them would be somewhat cumbersome and potentially slow.

Answer (score 2):

No its not possible, the whole concept of shaders is to be vectorizable so they can run in parallel. Even if you could there wouldn't be much gain as the GPUs speed advantage is(besides other things) inherently based on its capability to do computations in parallel. That aside, usually you have a combined view projection matrix that remains static during all draw calls(of a frame) and a model/world matrix attached to each object you're drawing.

The projection matrix does what its name implies projecting the points in a either perspective or orthogonal manner(you can think of this as the lense of your camera).
The view matrix is a transform to translate/rotate that projection(camera position and orientation) while the per-object world/model matrix contains the transformations(translation,rotation and scale) of the individual object.

In your shader you then transform your vertex position to world space using the per-object model/world matrix and then finally transform it to camera space using the premultiplied ViewProjection matrix:

```
gl_Position = matViewProjection * (matWorld * vPosition)
```

As you're drawing points depending on your usecase you could reduce the world matrix to just a translation vector.